# How to write this Objective-C Code into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a method in Objective-C that i'm trying to call in Swift.

```
    [TestObjectLoader loadObject:summaryMetrics fromJSONFile:@"SummaryMetrics" withMapping:[MappingProvider summaryMetricsMapping]];
```

[image]

This method loads a JSON file, and when I try to use the loadObject method, my approach is

TestObjectLoader.loadObject(summaryMetrics, fromJSONFile:"SummaryMetrics", withMapping:MappingProvider.summaryMetricsMapping())
[image]

But the auto-complete does not come up. I do have a bridging file that is working, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong..

Error Message: 
TestObjectLoader.Type does not have a member named loadObject

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is TestObjectLoader a valid object?

Comment: Yes it is, it's fully functional in objective-c

Comment: Did you instantiate an instance of TestLoader? It looks like you're calling it as a static.

Comment: var loader:TestObjectLoader = TestObjectLoader();
Like this?

Comment: If thats the case then your code would be `loader.loadObject(summaryMetrics, fromJSONFile:"SummaryMetrics", withMapping:MappingProvider.summaryMetricsMapping())`

Comment: That's what I have..

Comment: No you're  calling on the class not an instance of it

Comment: @VarunVarahabotla do you have the bridging header?

Comment: Is your complaint that the code doesn't compile or the autocomplete doesn't work?

Comment: @Aggressor I tried both ways, and they both don't work/complile.

Comment: @Boon It doesn't compile.

Comment: Please include compiler error.

Comment: TestObjectLoader.Type does not have a member named loadObject

Comment: @Subbu Yes, i have the bridging header and it is functional.

Comment: Can you show the complete code where you made this call?

Comment: it is in the new edited question!

Comment: Why is your code in the screenshot different than what you posted in the question?

Comment: @Aggressor told me I should make an instance, so i made an instance of Loader... that is all

Comment: How come you know your bridging header is working?

Comment: You cannot use instance.  Please attach the correct compiler message using the original code.

Comment: @Boon It's the exact same.

Comment: @Aggressor I can call TestObjectLoader from my swift file

Answer (score 1):

In general, the equivalent Swift syntax would be:

```
TestObjectLoader.loadObject(summaryMetrics, fromJSONFile:"SummaryMetrics", withMapping:MappingProvider.summaryMetricsMapping())
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, but it doesn't work. "TestObjectLoader.Type does not have a member named loadObject"

Comment: Doesn't work means autocomplete doesn't work or code?